# Bigquery load data in Day-partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create day-partitioned data and load data from Cloude Storage.
Step I've done

1. bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY myDataSet.dailytable
2. bq load --source_format=AVRO myProjectId:myDataSet.dailytable$20150510 gs://myBucket/path/2016-05-10/*

Actual result:

I have 2 tables: dailyTable and dailyTable$0150510

Expected result:

I have 2 tables dailyTable and dailyTable$**2**0150510

Is that expected behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Unix shell '$' is a special character, you will need to escape it, or put the whole table name in single quotes as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#addressing_table_partitions

You will not end up with two tables this way. The myDataSet.dailytable will have a single partitioned 'myDataSet.dailytable$20150510' corresponding to the 10th of May 2015. The partition is addressable as if it were a table.

Comment: Thanks, it helps.  bq load --source_format=AVRO 'myProjectId:myDataSet.dailytable$20160510' gs://myBucket/2016-05-10/* works fine

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcard to avoid loading day at a time?

Comment: It isn't possible at this point. We are working on support for  partitioning on a user specified date or timestamp column and you will be able to use the table name directly at that point. We will provide updates when we have the feature available. Thanks!

Comment: @PavanEdara any more information about this feature? Would be really helpful when loading "legacy" data into BQ.